# Visual Studio 2010 crashes repeatedly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

I've been running Visual Studio 2010 (the official release) for some time now. Lately, VS will crash 10+ times during my 8 hour work day. In VS2008, crashes were common when working with large Xaml files, and while I experience some of that with VS2010, crashes occur when debugging, starting the debugger, stopping the debugger, and other random times when editing code.

I've looked through the problem reports, and the one I've found that occurs most frequently is:

> **Description**
>
> Faulting Application Path:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>
> **Problem signature**
>
> Problem Event Name:           APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:         devenv.exe
>
> Application Version:          10.0.30319.1
>
> Application Timestamp:    4ba1fab3
>
> Fault Module Name:            ntdll.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:         6.1.7600.16385
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdb3b
>
> Exception Code:           c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:         0002e23e

I'm running Windows 7 (x64). Hoepfully someone has come across this problem and has found a solution. I plan on reinstalling VS2010. Hopefully that takes care of the problem.

Comment: nothing in event log? No more details?

Comment: If you look deeper into the event log there should be a field with bucket in the name.  Could you post that information?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what log am I looking at? I've searched through ActivityLog.xml and the problem reports from VS2010 crashes (accessed through Window 7's activity center), but I don't see anything with 'bucket' in the name.

Comment: This is strange. I am having the same problem, but I am running Windows XP, and I thought that was the cause.  My colleague, who is using Windows 7 says Visual Studio has been working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what was causing the problem. VS works fine on two other computers (both Windows 7, both 64-bit).

Comment: I've had problems once with invalid code. One class used to have invalid properties. Though there was no compiler warning, Visual Studio used to crash whenever I tried to open a xaml that depended on this code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you think you have installed any extra Extensions which might lead to frequent crashes?

You can try

```
Devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

to start in Safe mode. You can also try

```
Devenv.exe /Log
```

Which will log all activity. Have not tried this so don't know What activities are logged.

[Visual Studio 2010 Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the problem, but even in SafeMode VS2010 crashes. I just finished reinstalling everything to no avail. If I do ever come up with a solution (apart from formatting the computer), I'll post it.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer to the question? Did Quenton Jones find an answer??

Comment: @StealthRabbi It actually helped me. I had to start VS in safe mode and then just close it and afterwards I was able to start VS normally without any error.

Comment: It worked fine for me, even without restart VS. The problem was caused by cancelling de SP1 installation.

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar problem and this helped me

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618802/visual-studio-random-frequent-crash

Running this from the command prompt seemed to fix it. It hasn't crashed for the whole day today.

```
regsvr32 c:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with Visual Studio. The problem was the service pack which for some reason was not installed properly.

I had to reapply the SP1 using the Repair / reapply option. This kind of fixed my issue.

Also make sure to reboot the system.

Answer (score 2):

Just to help people who search it: It was webex instant messenger related part, but not Cisco itself. The cause was a component in Studio Power Tools relevant to integration with messenger. Reinstall power tools but without messaging integration.

In other occasion it is almost always a corporate antivirus authentication helper thing. It required to manually remove registry entries which cause background TFS logins break the studio at random moments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working" error, imediately when Visual Studio 2010 was starting. Fault module was clr.dll in my case. Only rebooting helped sometimes.

I solved it by removing .NET completely and reinstalling it.

Be aware that if you updated to .NET 4.5 this includes .NET 4, so you have to remove and reinstall .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

I know why it could be crashing. Code it self. Have you tried to debug the failed instance of VS2010 with Vs2010? If the xaml designer crashed anywhere in your code you should be able to see the stack trace. Also, try to load the same xaml into Blend 4 and then run the vs2010 on Blend when that crashes. I've had some good results debugging Vs2010 crashes like that.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm no longer working on the project that was giving me so many problems, but if I ever have difficulties again, I'll take a look. VS should handle bad code if this is the case tough.

Comment: not sure about the xaml stuff, but I'm getting repeated crashes in one install, one one box, very annoying, always get a msg about lost link to VS macros, so might be one of my custom macros. When I do debug with a new instance I get msg about Memory exception, like deven.exe is trying to process data as commands or commands as data, but not sure. annoyingly don't have time to fix it catch22 :)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things that can cause studio to crash.

I'd look at everything from video card drivers to whether the RAM is stable.

Note, there is a microsoft connect but on this exact issue at: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634162/devenv-exe-frequent-intermittent-crashes-fault-module-name-ntdll-dll

You might vote on it or add your own information to the report but the very first thing I'd do is update my video drivers.  One place I was at had a lot of issues with 2005; it would randomly crash just displaying the design surface or when opening a few too many code files; but once we got decent video cards and the appropriate drivers installed it worked flawlessly.

Comment: will try this when I get a free minute, thanks for info on your experience. chrs.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled “Options"-"Evnironment"-"Add-in/Micros Security"->"Allow macros to run", and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solved a similar issue on my computer, but probably not the same cause. It was related to TortoiseSVN (I think visual loads the tortoise DLL because it is integrated with the explorer, even if I don't have a specific visual studio plug-in). I upgraded TortoiseSVN (from 1.7.8 to 1.7.11) and it didn't crash for a few hours (I also had a 100% repro case when closing visual studio which does not happen anymore). Maybe there is some way to check what DLLs are loaded by visual studio to troubleshoot what are the candidates for upgrading/uninstalling, but I didn't go this far.

Hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

While developing **C++** code, Visual Studio 2010 started crashing frequently and at random times after I enabled the [Task List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535415/1497596).

As an alternative to using the Task List, I am now simply using the **Find in Files** tool (Ctrl+Shift+F) and searching for the string `TODO` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

i was having a similar problem.  visual studio 2010 was crashing.  when i attached, it said it had a read access violation in ntdll.dll

closed all my open instances (there were 5) and it stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this error, in my case it was because Microsoft released the update (KB2858725) the FrameWork 4.5.1, which the download and installed,

However this is definitely addressed by performing the following steps:

1. FrameWork 4.5.1 download (KB2858728) => NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-ENU.exe-Allos 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779
2. Install the downloaded software (KB2858728)
3. Try Vs, but give the same error.
4. Uninstall the downloaded software (KB2858728) 
   (this task fully cleaned upgrade giving problems (KB2858725)
5. Install the downloaded software (KB2858728) again
6. Try Vs, this time if it will work

NOTE: NEVER! install update (KB2858725)

Answer (score 0):

Logging helps indeed. I have the same problem with crashes. Since there could be numerous reasons and lots of log data, I wrote this .bat (Win7 x64, VS2010 Express) to keep logs organized and easy to analyze:

```
    @echo off

    rem date and time in format YYYYMonDD_hhmmss
    set year=%DATE:~-4%
    set month=%DATE:~3,2%
    set day=%DATE:~0,2%

    IF %month%==01 set monthstr=Jan
    IF %month%==02 set monthstr=Feb
    IF %month%==03 set monthstr=Mar
    IF %month%==04 set monthstr=Apr
    IF %month%==05 set monthstr=May
    IF %month%==06 set monthstr=Jun
    IF %month%==07 set monthstr=Jul
    IF %month%==08 set monthstr=Aug
    IF %month%==09 set monthstr=Sep
    IF %month%==10 set monthstr=Oct
    IF %month%==11 set monthstr=Nov
    IF %month%==12 set monthstr=Dec

    set now=%TIME:~0,-3%
    set now=%now::=%
    set now=%now: =0%
    set now=%year%%monthstr%%day%_%now%

    start "VS2010 express" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCExpress.exe" /Log "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSlogs\VS_log_%now%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I cleared my settings. Configured environment to use C# development settings. Then i disabled all extensions against which disable button was present. I enabled them one by one while opening, running and closing solutions. I found the offending extension to be .Net reflector v 8.5.0.179 by red gate. I had VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 all installed on my windows 8.1 enterprise 64bit. All of them had the same issue. Whenever i closed the solution VS would crash. Hope it helps.