# How do I make TODO comments show up in the task list for C++ projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, todo

I'm trying to get my TODO comments to show up in the task list in Visual Studio 2010 for a C++ project, but they don't.  I looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but see no caveats other than the TODO comments need to be in the currently-open file.  For example, creating a new Win32 console app places this:

```
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

in a new file, stdafx.h.  However, there's nothing in the task list.

I have "Comments" chosen from the drop-down in the task list, but it's always empty.  And it's not [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663914/todo-comments-are-not-showing-up-in-the-task-list); I can open the file and be looking at the TODO comment in the code editor and no task is shown.  This is not a problem for C# projects as TODO comments show up as designed in those projects; this appears to be an issue specific to C++ projects.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is off by default 'for performance reasons'.  Tools + Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Formatting, Miscellaneous, Enumerate Comment Tasks = True.  Feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/580970/task-list-comments-not-working).

Also note the comment in the MSDN article about task list comments:

> With Visual C++ projects, the Task
>   List displays only the comments that
>   are found in the file that is
>   currently active in the editor.

Comment: Ok I found it, on VS2013 Express it can be found at: Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->View-> Miscellaneous->Enumerate Comment Tasks.

The problem is, it is already set to true.

Comment: @NeonWarge same for me. it is set to true but the tasks from the comments are showing up only if the document is opened :/

Comment: @sami1592 true, its hard to deal with especially if you want to see your todos for those code. Well I guess maybe I am using it wrong, maybe they intentionally wanted you to view TODOs only for the opened file. Though, It wouldn't hurt them to include a window that shows all TODOs in the project.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I got from MSDN:

> Hi,
>
> The ‘comments tasks’ in the Task List window is turned off by default
> due to performance reasons. You can turn this feature on from
>
> Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->
> Miscellaneous->Enumerate Comment Tasks.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thanks Sumit Kumar Visual C++ Team