# Todo tasks not appearing in the Task List in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, comments, todo

I've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and haven't have any problems except for the fact that comments beginning with "//todo" no longer show up in the task list. I have absolutely no idea on where to start looking for a solution to this problem as all of the keywords are too general.

I came across other similar questions where the answer was that the file wasn't open containing the //todo comment, but that is not the case for me. My todo comments do not show up even when the file is open in front of me.

Comment: Do comments starting with `// TODO:` show up in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The //todo comments do get highlighted as if they are added to the task list, but they simply aren't displayed.

Comment: Same for VS2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535363/how-do-i-make-todo-comments-show-up-in-the-task-list-for-c-projects-in-visual

Comment: Does anyone have any idea where the category drop down moved for vs2015?

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Same problem here.

Comment: Same problem still exists in VS2017 :-/

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Actually there is a dropdown control at the top of the "**Task List**" window and if you use the **Visual Studio 2012 Dark Theme** the dropdown looks like a label. If you click the "**User Tasks**" text, you will see "**Comments**" selection which lists your comments that contain "//todo".

[image: Screenshot]

[Enlarge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqMff.png)

Comment: Dang! I looked and looked and couldn't see that.

Comment: @Furkan Elkinici, I did what you said but nothing happen in my case. it it the same blank Task List

Comment: @Rania-Boy do you use Visual Studio 2012 and Dark Theme?

Comment: @FurkanEkinci: yes, but even if it is light or blue, the theme does not matter. Anyhow, now it is working. check my answer below ..

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't see that xD @MrX, Thank you !!

Answer (score 41):

** For Visual Studio 2012 **

1. Select View -> Other  Windows -> Task List.

[image]

2. Select the option "Comments" in the Task List window.

   [image]

**For Visual Studio 2008.**

In the Task List window select the option "Comments".

[image]

Comment: @RckLN: I have the same problem but in windows-7 and VS2012. I followed your short and very-useful tutorial but the problem stands still and I can't see my "//TODO" comment in the Task List

Comment: @RckLN: I have figured it out, see my answer below. i was just missing the colon after the token.

Answer (score 8):

You can view what you have set for tokens in Tools/Options under the Environment/Task List item in the left tree.  You should have "TODO" in there which should detect `//todo`.

Comment: This was not the correct answer, but it was very, very useful. The cause was a dropdown box containing the items 'comments' and 'user tasks'. As this new dark theme tucks away the dropdown icon, I believed it was simply a title and not a dropdown box. 'user tasks' was selected while what was needed was 'comments'.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I was Having the same problem working in Windows-7 and Visual Studio 2012. All I had to do is change from:

`// TODO`

to

`// TODO: do not forget the colon`

Comment: The colon really should not affect the todo's appearing unless you have messed up your settings under tools-> options-> environment-> Task List

Comment: @SamuelDavis: the colon made all the difference for me. My settings were and still fine as after installing VS-2012 (fresh installation) I haven't touched them. In fact, I was able to add two more tokens but again I have to put the colon in order to be identified as "Task List"

Comment: @Rania-Boy yup, made all the difference for me, the lil bugg(...)

Comment: @Irfan: for some of us the use of the colon is vital while it's not with others.I guess we are missing a very tiny small setting-detail, we need to find it out because it may be affecting other things as well ..

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! Note that you have to have a space after the colon as well.

Comment: @Suda.nese Thanks ! Works for me but need exactly "// TODO:", case and space.

Answer (score 3):

Chalk this up to a stupid mistake, if it is not showing for you make sure your code doesn't look like this:

```
//int justfakecode=1; // TODO: FIX ME LATER
```

with the token as part of a commented out line. I herped the derp on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Task list comments just shows current files TODO comments. This may be a bug of Visual Studio.

Comment: The original post references VS 2012. Since newer versions have been released, it is possible it is no longer a bug. Have you checked with 2015? Also, this question already has an accepted answer. The fact that you are providing (probably already known) details about 2+ year old software -- it is a little extraneous to SO. I did not flag, but I did downvote.

Comment: Confirmed in VS 2015 as well in some cases. Upvoted to counteract onebree's downvote.