# Task List type selection box gone in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015

My task list is empty.  The answer seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290235/todo-tasks-not-appearing-in-the-task-list-in-visual-studio-2012) except that the drop down doesn't appear at all.  It looks like this:

[image: task list dialog, no drop-down for type selection]

Anyone know how to get the drop-down back in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the drop-down to switch between the user tasks and comments: It has been removed in VS 2015 because the user tasks have been removed as well. See here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1659843/task-list-window-no-longer-supports-user-tasks-in-vs2015

Comment: Those bastards.  Thanks.  Off to MSDN to complain...!