# Visual Studio Cannot Open Certain Project in A Solution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing this problem after I cleaned and attempt to rebuild all my projects in a solutions. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and building an application based using Vb.Net

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.30319.1
  Application Timestamp:    4ba1fab3
  Fault Module Name:    msvbide.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.30319.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba201ae
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00159311
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1057
```

What I have tried so far :

- Remove *.suo files
- Start Devenv.exe in safemode
- Start Devenv.exe in with Log. The link of log file will be posted below.
- Start one of the projects without the solution, problem still persists.
- Turn off "Allows macro to run"
- Restart my computer.

The error only happens in one particular solution. I tried to open another solution, nothing happens.

Here is link to the log I've taken prior to the [VS_Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B38Yl_iPquc7cmdrRGM1ZXh5Rjg)

Can anyone help me fix this problem, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407777/visual-studio-2010-crashes-repeatedly

Comment: @JimHewitt tried safe mode, problem still persist. The error only happens in 1 solution, while the other solution remains okay. Should i post the logging result here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to fix my problem. 
Turns out that some of the projects in my solution and DLLs are corrupted.

**You need to have a back up of your solution before you attemp this. Please do back up your solution regularly.**

So this is what I do :

1. Create a new solution
2. Copy all the projects folder from the previous corrupted solution to the newly created solution
3. Removed the corrupted DLLs folder.
4. Add existing project to the new solution one by one to isolate the corrupted project.
5. Build the project to determine whether the project is corrupted or no.
6. Replace the corrupted project with project from back up folder and repeat step 4 and 5.
7. Repeat step 4 - 6 until all projects have been successfully loaded.
8. Debug the solution.

It seems that Visual Studio corrupted the DLLs and some projects while attempting to clean and rebuild, although I cannot pinpoint where exactly the corrupted part is.

I hope my case can help many people who is experiencing the same problem as I had.

Best Regard,

Je Ha